# downgrading xcb-* packages to 1.11 on debian

Tags: debian, apt, xcb

I'm trying to compile `polybar`, and  I get a long compilation error which is related to xcb (apparently), I have the log file [here](https://pastebin.com/fLAGZSjL); I've read through the polybar wiki and I came upon the solution of downgrading `xcb-proto` to `1.11`, and so I followed through with the process, although I'm not really sure how to check ther version (the logs tell me that each X-extension has version 1.13 though?)

Nonetheless I've tried compiling with both Clang and GCC using `build.sh`, all to no avail, my question is how I can downgrade packages:

```
-- [X]   xcb-randr (1.13.1)
-- [X]   xcb-randr (monitor support) (1.13.1)
-- [X]   xcb-composite (1.13.1)
-- [X]   xcb-xkb (1.13.1)
[...]
```

to version 1.11?

EDIT

I have tried to remove the `libxcb*` packages from my Debian, and before I wrote `yes` on the prompt to continue I noticed it would make redundant a lot of packages that would otherwise be beneficial to my system, so I don't see how I can hotplug a downgrade without removing the packages I want to downgrade to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to answer to original issue of polybar not compiling. It's most likely not an issue with the version installed through `apt`. That particular issue only occurs on systems where `xcb-proto` is version 1.12 and `libxcb-randr0-dev` is 1.11, but since all are 1.13.1, you should be fine.

The issue you have in your logs:

```
ERROR: could not calc required_start_align of Struct "xcb.Setup
```

Appeared before, [here](https://github.com/polybar/polybar/issues/1629). There the issue was that anaconda was used for python, which caused loads of problems.

There are instructions on the [wiki](https://github.com/polybar/polybar/wiki/Known-Issues#building-with-anaconda-installed) on how to compile polybar while anaconda is installed (without uninstalling anaconda). The easiest way that people have reported working is to run `conda deactivate` in the terminal where you are compiling polybar before compiling. Also make sure that you completely redownload the tar-archive (or do a clean git clone) before building.

Comment: that appears to cause more confusion since i don't have anaconda installed, all my builds of python are source-built besides the system python (i have python 3.7.3 and 3.8.0b3); i'll try to downgrade my main `python3` back to 3.7.3 -- edit: it appears polybar only cares about python 2 so i don't see how it should matter

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly I solved this by simplying recloning the polybar repository, configuring with `-DWITH_XRANDR_MONITORS=0` (although this isn't necessary I don't think) and voila. I have no idea why this worked but the only significant things I have done are reinstall `xcb-proto` after downgrading it (supposedly) to version `1.11`.